# EXCEL: Check if a Time is between two times

Tags: excel, if-statement, time

I am trying to make a check for is a scheduled time lies between Rush Hour.  I define rush hour as between 6:00-10:00 and 15:00-19:00.

[Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqwgl.png)

Comment: Time is stored as a number in excel and the way to do this with a number is to check for between.... i.e. `AND( x > This , x < This)`. If you want to check for both then you would add a `OR` operator like `OR( AND(x > This, x < This) , AND(x > This, x < This))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
=OR(AND(B1<TIME(19,0,0),B1>TIME(15,0,0)),AND(B1<TIME(10,0,0),B1>TIME(6,0,0)))
```